# Incorrect upload file use FileOutputStream. Incorrect size

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

When I try upload the file from server, I use this code. I get the file size of 500kb, when the original file size about 300kb.
What am I doing wrong?

```
attachmentContent = applicationApi.getApplicationAttachmentContent(applicationame);  
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(attachmentContent.getAttachmentContent().getInputStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n=0;
while (-1 !=(n=in.read(buf)))
{
    out.write(buf,0,n);
}
out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
File transferredFile = new File(attachmentName);
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(transferredFile);
attachmentContent.getAttachmentContent().writeTo(outStream);
outStream.write(response);
outStream.close();
```

Simplify. The same result:

```
File transferredFile = new File(attachmentName);
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(transferredFile);
attachmentContent.getAttachmentContent().writeTo(outStream);
outStream.close();
```

Comment: Not sure why you are doing this `attachmentContent.getAttachmentContent().writeTo(outStream);` It looks like you are writing the file twice

Answer (score 0):

The `ByteArrayOutputStream` is a complete waste of time and space. You're reading the attachment twice, and writing it twice too. Just read from the attachment and write directly to the file. Simplify, simplify. You don't need 90% of this.

Comment: This is utterly impossible to believe. You are writing the data once instead of twice. You cannot possibly get the same result.

Comment: but File size does't change. Maybe I'm wrong doing somewhere else